# How to compare two time timestamp

Tags: c++

I need to compare the two-time timestamp of the file modified time and current local time.

Once the file timestamp has been changed I would like to run the following statements with continuous monitoring = while loop

I tried converting time_t values of file and current local time to string with ctime conversion but how can I compare the two ctime values?
And I also tried to store the ctime string to char* and tried to compare the following strings but no result

```
struct stat attr;
stat(path, &attr);
ctime(&attr.st_mtime) /*  modified time of a file in a string format */

time_t  timev;
time(&timev); 
ctime(&timev) ;

if (ctime(&timev) != ctime(&attr.st_mtime) ){
printf("enter code here statements");
}
else{
printf("enter code here statements");
}


char* string;
char* buffertime1 ;

string = ctime(&attr.st_mtime) ;
buffertime1 = ctime(&timev) ;

if (string !=buffertime1  ){
printf(enter code here statements);
}
else{
printf(enter code here statements);
}

 int result = strcmp(buffertime1, buffertime);

 if (result == 0){
 std::cout << "Both Strings are equal" << std::endl;
  }
 else{
  std::cout << "Both Strings are not equal";
  }
```

Comment: I suspect you're trying to compare strings wiith `(string !=buffertime1  )` (and several other places). That won't work, you need to use strcmp.

Comment: This is typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where Y here is how to compare time strings (ctime) and X  some time operation. Please read link and rephrase question.

Comment: I am tried with strcmp in my code but for some reason both strings compared as equal even though they are not equal because with while loop the current local time keep on updating and the modified time of the file will be constant until the next update